Jenkins How To Upload File To Build Workspace After Build Complete With CURL
I have a jenkins pipeline that runs some docker containers over ssh on external servers, it monitors the containers until they've all completed.
I need each container to be able to post a file to the jenkins build, i was under the impression this could be done with a curl request such as this example:
curl -v -X POST --user username:api-key-here --form "file=@/path/to/local/file.txt" http://my-jenkins-url.com/job/job%20name/63/ws

Where "63" is the build number
Jenkins version: 2.454
The curl response says it was ok, but no files appear in the workspace in jenkins


Accept: /
Content-Length: 189
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------bfba94ff096e5f3f


We are completely uploaded and fine



Are the containers orchestrated by Jenkins? Do they appear as agents in Jenkins UI?

@Iterokun it's not related to the containers, i've tried the curl request manually from my machine and it doesn't upload the file, returns with 302 unless i add a trailing slash after "ws" which then returns html as though there was an error - but no error in jenkins logs

If those containers are Jenkins agents you have a couple of sane options how to handle this :) - stash and artifact. Moving files to your controller workspace is a hack - controller might not even have the workspace, generally speaking.
